# Windows Azure is currently performing an operation on the related affinity group that requires exclusive access

Tags: windows, azure, deployment, upload, portal

When uploading packages through Azure Management Portal (manage.windowsazure.com), I've been getting this error (see title) more and more frequently in the past few days.

**What I am uploading**

I upload 4 packages to Azure every time we have a release:

- consumer site
- administration site
- WCF
- sub-admin site

**Usage History**

A year ago, I used to be able to upload all 4 asynchronously.

6 months ago, something (bug?) occurred where if I upload more than 1 file without refreshing the portal page, it would completely ignore successive file uploads.

The last few days, however, I have been receiving *"Windows Azure is currently performing an operation on the related affinity group that requires exclusive access"* if any of my applications are still becoming Ready/Running.

**Current Problem**

For me to upload all 4 packages, I must upload one package, wait for it to reach the "Running" state, and then repeat for the remaining packages.

It takes 5-10 minutes for each package uploaded to reach the "Running" state for all instances (ranging from 1-4 instances).

Right now it doesn't seem like there is any articles or blogs acknowledging this issue. If anyone has any advice, please share.

Comment: Been having the same issue. I haven't found a solution yet though.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this issue was temporary, and has gone away as of a week or so ago.

I haven't run into the issue , nor have I seen any blog posts or anything similar acknowledging that this was an issue.

The issue regarding "upload more than 1 file without refreshing the portal page" also seems to be fixed.